# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, spyder

In MacOS, I used Pip to install tensorflow following the standard instructions on the tensorflow.org website.

When I start Spyder, I am able to execute the following instruction without error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

But when I attempt to run the following instruction: g = tf.Graph(), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

When I do the same in "python" or "ipython" instead of Spyder, I do not get this error.  But I would like to use Spyder.

I tried the install with Conda instead of Pip, but got the same symptoms.

Comment: What does `dir(tf)` print?

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'np', 'pickle', 'print_function', 'range', 'tf']

Comment: That's strange. I am not sure why you have a `tf` symbol in the `tf` module. Just out of curiosity, what does `dir(tf.tf)` print?

Comment: Same answer!  See below:

dir(tf.tf)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'np', 'pickle', 'print_function', 'range', 'tf']

Comment: Is there any chance that you're importing a script of your own, named "tensorflow.py", that is in the same directory of your current script?  
In that case, remove or rename that script and try again.

Comment: Thanks Roberto - that solved the problem!  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps worked for me: (linux, pip, tf1.4-gpu)

- Uninstall tensorflow

  `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`
- Delete pip caches

  `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip/*`
- Re-install tensorflow

  `pip install -U tensorflow-gpu`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming in recent times, this error might come up when using Keras. Solved it by changing all

```
from keras.something import something
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.something import something
```

Can see [github issue about this.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12379#issue-416379765)